# 'reader' is never closed... How to solve this?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class even {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int num = reader.nextInt();
        if(num % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println(num + " is even");
        else
            System.out.println(num + " is odd");
    }

}
```

> it is showing the error that "reader is never closed"...

Comment: call reader.close() at the end.

Comment: `Scanner` has a `close()` method that should be called

Comment: Except there's really no need to close `System.in`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to do `reader.close();` before you exit your function or after you are done with the object:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class even {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int num = reader.nextInt();
        if(num % 2 == 0)
            System.out.println(num + " is even");
        else
            System.out.println(num + " is odd");

        reader.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I m new at the java... Can you please provide me the exact code

Comment: @AashishJha A general advice for you, whenever you got any error or confusion, just google it, do some research on it. If you still couldn't figure it out. Then ask for help

Comment: @AashishJha no problem. I am glad that I could help you.